# EF update list members of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity which has a collection of another entity as a property. How can I check if any of the entities in the list are different than the members of the list of the entity that I got as a parameter, and is an expensive operation? Does the example code below replace the list of the entity in the DB for the list of the entity in the parameters?

Example:

```
    class A
    {
      public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set;}
      Some other properties
    }
    class B
    {
      public int AID { get; set;}
      public virtual A A { get; set;}
      Some other properties
    }
    Controller
    {
      public async Task<bool> updateA(A a)
      {
         A newA= new A{ ID = a.ID};
         db.As.Attach(newA);
         newA.Bs= a.Bs;
      }
    }
```

Comment: When you assign `newA.Bs = a.Bs` then you are effectively replacing the reference `newA.Bs` had with `a.Bs`, you merely want to run a LINQ statement to generate you a new list

Comment: I'm using this for single value properties, is it psosible to use it for collections ?    
db.Entry(newA).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
              var entry = db.Entry(newA);
            entry.Property(r => r.someproperty).IsModified = true;

Comment: What I find the best thing is to do, is to blast away all from `newA.Bs` because that is getting overwritten by `a.Bs`. Doesn't matter if there are existing items, because they get replaced by new items that are exactly the same